# Need to make exsiting spring application as SAML WebSSO Identity Provider

Tags: spring-security, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml

We have a existing Spring application. We have a case now where we need to integrate an application which already acts as SAML WebSSO Service Provider. We need to act as IDP initiated SAML SSO which will post SAML assertion to a given URL of Service Provider for seamless login. I need guidance if we can use Spring Security SAML extension for this purpose. If yes, can anyone provide step by step sample for that. If no, any guidance regarding this would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

No, Spring SAML doesn't act as an Identity Provider and doesn't create authentication assertions for 3rd parties. Though for simple use cases it would be an easy extension to make.

Comment: Would OpenSAML help me in this regard? I read another question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28030031/creating-saml-indentity-assertion-in-spring-web-app?rq=1

where you answered the same question. Am I on the right direction ?

Comment: Yes, you can build any SAML-based system with OpenSAML, both Spring SAML and Shibboleth is built on top of it as well.